# Debugging Cordova + Chrome + App

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, cordova

i'm using Cordova Chrome App with Android ADT Bundle.
I have made a test application that runs ok in web browser and as web app for chrome.
But when i run the app for android window.close() doesn't work when i create the "native" app for android.
I read about other methods in cordova and chrome.app... but it is difficult for me because i can not debug using console.log in android emulator.
My questions:
How can i close the app?
How can i debug through console.log for example?
I read and try log cat, etc. but it doesn't show anything from javascript

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below line of code to exit the app.

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```